# CuPy and Dirichlet gives me TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: numpy, cupy, numpy-random

I simply want to create a random matrix A whose vectors are drawn from the Dirichlet distribution. The function works fine with [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.dirichlet.html):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(n), n)
```

When I do the same thing with [cupy](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.random.dirichlet.html)

```
import cupy as cp
A = cp.random.dirichlet(cp.ones(n), n)
```

I get the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-45a4f64a8b6e> in <module>
      6 n = 10000 #Size of the square matrix
      7 
----> 8 A = cp.random.dirichlet(cp.ones(n), n)
      9 
     10 print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\cupy\random\_distributions.py in dirichlet(alpha, size, dtype)
    112     """
    113     rs = _generator.get_random_state()
--> 114     return rs.dirichlet(alpha, size, dtype)
    115 
    116 

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\cupy\random\_generator.py in dirichlet(self, alpha, size, dtype)
    144             size = alpha.shape
    145         else:
--> 146             size += alpha.shape
    147         y = cupy.empty(shape=size, dtype=dtype)
    148         _kernels.standard_gamma_kernel(alpha, self._rk_seed, y)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

When the input is a numpy array like this

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np

A = cp.random.dirichlet(np.ones(n), n)
```

then I get the same error.

The `alpha.shape` from line 146 is (n,) when I check manually. Is it a cupy bug or am I missing something?

I'm using cupy-cuda101 version 8.5.0 for CUDA 10.1. Everything else that has to do with cupy and tensorflow works perfectly on my GPU (2080ti).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in cupy which you should report on their GitHub.

They do not properly handle the case of an integer argument, despite the documentation. They require that you provide either a tuple or `None`. This is why you see the behavior you’re seeing. (If you provided a tuple `(a, b)`, then the resulting shape would properly be `(a, b, n)`.

The workaround here is to provide the shape you want as a length-1 tuple: `(n,)`. Note that the comma is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I will report it on their GitHub. This workaround works.

Comment: Update: I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/pull/4772) to correct this.

Comment: Great, I hope it gets merged soon. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the pull-request! We'll include it in the next release.